# How to parse a list of waypoints using python and xml.etree?

Tags: python, xml, tree

The following list of Points represent a track

```
   <Track_Vertices>
        <Point1>36 35.58 N, 1 8.91 W</Point1>
        <Point2>36 42.56 N, 0 56.27 W</Point2>
        <Point3>36 40.91 N, 0 54.86 W</Point3>
        <Point4>36 33.94 N, 1 7.5 W</Point4>
        <Point5>36 32.29 N, 1 6.09 W</Point5>
        <Point6>36 39.27 N, 0 53.45 W</Point6>
        <Point7>36 37.62 N, 0 52.04 W</Point7>
        <Point8>36 30.64 N, 1 4.68 W</Point8>
        <Point9>36 28.99 N, 1 3.27 W</Point9>
        <Point10>36 35.97 N, 0 50.63 W</Point10>
```

Every track has a diferent number of waypoints.

The waypoint position is parsed as follows.

```
root.find("*SRU_Track_Vertices/Point1")
```

buy I don´t know the number after "Pointx", a them I am trying something like

```
root.findall("*SRU_Track_Vertices/Point*")
```

How can I do that not using Regex ?

Comment: try using this,  `root.findall("contains(text(), 'Point')")`

Comment: Does a ```<Track_Vertices>``` element contain anything other than ```Pointxyz``` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply invoke `.text` - You can output all waypoints with something like this:

```
track = root.find('.//Track_Vertices')

for i in range(1, len(track)+1):
    waypoint = track.find('Point{}'.format(i)).text

    print(waypoint)
```

For all `<Track_Vertices>` elements:

```
tracks = root.findall('.//Track_Vertices')

for t in tracks:

    for i in range(1, len(t)+1):
        waypoint = t.find('Point{}'.format(i)).text

        print(waypoint)
```

Comment: I don't know the entire structure of your xml, a bit more would be helpful. Is the `Track_Vertices` element the root of the tree?

Comment: Great, glad I could help.